RDS Permissions through IAM user
My RDS user lacks the permissions to create schema's. Is it possible to grant this user these permissions through an IAM policy instead of granting me these permissions via the Database administrator? If so which policy?
ERROR:  permission denied for database {database name}
SQL state: 42501

Thanks in advance!
I have been looking through these pages to look for a suitable policy but I havent been able to find any.
RDS policy page

As far as I know, it's not possible, but you can create a lambda that login as admin on the rds database and create user/role/group

Thanks for your comment. Indeed what I want should just be done by the Database administrator. Thanks anyway for looking into it!
